# Getting DataSource resource in a Java web app

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, javabeans

I have the following resource tag in my context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/myApp">
  <Resource name="jdbc/myDS" auth="Container" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
    username="user" password="passwd"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB" />
</Context>
```

I am developing a Java web app using the Stripes framework in NetBeans.

How can I get this resource from within a Java class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need your bean to be instantiated by something (a dependecy injection framework) which knows how to handle the `@Resrouce` annotation. JSP itself doesn't know how.

In this case it would be simpler to locate the DataSource in the JNDI context:

```
Context initContext = new InitialContext();
Context envContext  = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
DataSource ds = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/myDS");
```

Comment: I'm sort of new to Java web apps... could you explain please?

Comment: Also, this is not in my JSP file, it is in my bean (i.e., Java class) file.

Comment: see my update for the JNDI. if you want to use the `@Resource` annotation you need to have someone to read it. JSP itself cannot read it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried this method (replacing the parameter to lookup with "jdbc/myDS") but I get an error: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Bozho for the answer.  I only had to change the lookup string to get it to work:

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource ds = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/myDS");
Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```