# tomcat sqlite jdbc on server connection problem

Tags: sqlite, tomcat, jdbc

Hi  i want to upload my wicket project into the tomcat server.

But in project i 've connected to db file like this :

> connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\Users\myPC\gr27hbs.db");

I'll make war file but server doesn't have db file.So i must put my db file into projects folder.But this time there is a problem in connection string there is a parameter which is illustrated with my pc user name.

Where should i put the db file , and how will tomcat knows where the database file is?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279632/how-to-configure-sqlite-in-tomcat-6 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770790/relative-path-to-sqlite-db-in-context-xml